Why are Git commands not working on my MacOS?
I'll preface this by saying that I'm a front end dum-dum that doesn't have a very thorough understanding of how command lines in a terminal relate to software on my computer.
When i tried "git log" today I got the message:

xcode-select: note: No developer tools were found, requesting install.
If developer tools are located at a non-default location on disk, use sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools, and cancel the installation dialog.
See man xcode-select for more details.

then a screen poped up to install something, and I let it install.
Now when I try "git log" I get the message:

fatal: Unable to read current working directory: Operation not permitted

What is happening?
I typed "git log" into the command line on my terminal and expected a list of past versions of my website, like I've done hundreds of times before. Instead I got this.
Update: I finally found an answer here:
Unable to read current working directory: Operation not permitted
I needed to go into System Settings, type "full disk access" in the search bar, click on "allow applications to use all user files" then click the switch near "terminal"on the right.
Here's a picture:
solution

Sounds like you don't have permission to read the current working directory; nothing to do with git.

I don't see, why git would invoke any xcode command, so the first error message is already weird. So first try a simple git help. If this works, do a git config --get-all and a git branch. Do they work? Can you access your working directory without using git, for instance using just ls?

@user1934428 git is part of the Xcode Command Line Tools, so that's where the error message comes from.

@user1934428  git help works, but git config --get-all produces the response "fatal: Unable to read current working directory: Operation not permitted"

So I guess you get the error too if you do a git config --global -l? That command needs to read only the git configuration file and is independent from the git configuration file. You can run it from outside your repo as well.

to install git, you can use terminal to do the following:
%> brew update
%> brew install git

Once you have git installed, you should cd <source/code/directory> Once your source is in current directory, you then need to do git init to initialize git which creates a local git repository.  Once created, you should be able to move forward with other git commands.

Will this erase the commits on my current Git repository? I've saved versions of this website going back years.

the local git repo is in a hidden folder in the source root folder named ".git".  notice the dot.  if this already exists in your source folder, the git init is not correct.  Try to do an ls -la and see if there is a ".git" already there.  In this case, you may not have the git binaries installed, which will be installed by the first part of my answer: brew install git.

try to do a git --version to check your version of the git binaries.

if your git binaries are installed, you may have a permission in your source folder.  you can check the permissions using the same command I mentioned earlier: ls -la

use git status to check for uncommitted changes in your source and make backups of your local source folder.

@Kbesh, you should have a git remote that you're pushing to, in which case, all your changes are in the remote and you can do a pull or a clone from the remote into another local directory.  :-)  good luck...

So when I try "%> brew update" Its says "fg: no current job," Just "brew update" gets me "zsh: command not found: brew"

I googled how to install brew on macos.

Use the following command to install brew:  %> /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

Kbesh, based on the comments attached above, it does seem like a permissions issue, which I mentioned earlier.  you'll need sudo access and will need to fix the permissions issues using chown, and or chgrp on the files within the local source directory.

%> ls -la will give you a long listing that shows the owner and group attributes.  Is your name attached to all the files listed in your project?
